# Issue with using devise gem authentication with Mobile app (Titanium)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, titanium-mobile

I am using Devise gem in my Rails app for authentication. I could able to create user by passing data in Json request format to devise rails app from Titanium mobile application.
But when i try to set up login in mobile app to use devise, it shows an error like below

```
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

My code looks like below

```
var regDetails = '{"email": "'+userNmTxt.value+'", "password": "'+passwordTxt.value+'"}';
       var client = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({timeout: 5000});
       client.open("POST", "http://10.100.85.43:3000/session/create");
       client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       client.send(regDetails);        
       client.onload = function(e)
       {
               alert('Logged in successfully' + this.responseText);
       }
       client.onerror = function(e)
       {
               alert('On error' + this.responseText);
       }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i was missing some routing information in `routes.rb` file

```
devise_scope :user do
   match "/session/create" => "session#create" #, :via => [:get, :post]
   match "/session/destroy" => "session#destroy" #, :via => [:get, :post] 
   match "/registration/create" => "registration#create" #, :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

Hope this will help someone :)